# Exception on HCBT_MOVESIZE when window is minimized

Tags: c++, winapi

I'm using `CBTProc` hook to keep a specific window in the desired size, however, when I minimize the window it does throw an exception at `int left   = rect->left;`.

I tried to check for `if (!IsRectEmpty(rect)) {` but it also does not work, what else I could try?

```
    case HCBT_MOVESIZE: // A window is about to be moved or sized. 
    {
        RECT* rect = reinterpret_cast<RECT*>(lParam);

        if (!IsRectEmpty(rect)) {
           int left   = rect->left;
           int top    = rect->top;
           int right  = rect->right;
           int bottom = rect->bottom;

           int width  = right - left;
           int height = bottom - top;


           if (width != 1000 || height != 600) {
              rc->right = left + 1000;
              rc->bottom = top + 600;
           }
        }
        return 0;
    }
```

Comment: Please provide a [mcve]

Comment: maybe rect is NULL ?

Comment: @SvenNilsson if it was null it wouldnt enter inside of the `if (!IsRectEmpty(rect))`?

Comment: Just add test `if(rect == NULL) return 0;`, otherwise `IsRectEmpty(rect)` is executed.

Comment: @Nature The `if` is always executed, and `IsRectEmpty()` does not support being passed a NULL `RECT*`, so it will always try to dereference the pointer to access the `RECT`.  So, if `rect` is NULL then you get Undefined Behavior and likely crash. On the other hand, `HCBT_MOVESIZE` is not documented as ever giving a NULL `RECT*` to begin with, as the hook is supposed to be able to modify the fields of the `RECT` to affect the window being moved/sized. So, I suspect there is something else going on with your code that you have not shown yet.

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.